# Uploading file using ajax (without FORM)

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have some files in the local and know the path of those files.
I'm trying to upload the file using AJAX.
How to upload the file using AJAX without using FORM.

```
enter code here
```

**NOTE**: I've the FileReader object of the file.
Please share if u have any idea.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot upload a file from the local computer unless triggered by the user (the user should select the file), you can upload a file with jQuery:

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

https://github.com/hayageek/jquery-upload-file